# Element changes after being pushed to my array - React Native

Tags: arrays, object, react-native, react-navigation

## Problem

When I set an object in a button navigation function and then navigate to the new screen, it outputs the wrong data.

## Code

Here is a replication and oversimplification of my problem. This is pseudo code and will not work, but it should give an idea for what is happening. I did not post my "real" code, because it is much more complex and I think that explaining it will take up unnecessary time, however if it is helpful just ask me and I will give it to you.

```
var array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  array.push(
    <button
      onPress={() => navigate('screen', {x:i} )}
      key={'img' + i}
      title={'click me'}
    />
    )
}

//after navigation to screen
console.log(params.x);
//x:10
console.log(params.x);
//x:10
console.log(params.x);
//x:10
console.log(params.x);
//x:10
console.log(params.x);
//x:10
console.log(params.x);
//x:10
console.log(params.x);
//x:10
console.log(params.x);
//x:10
console.log(params.x);
//x:10
console.log(params.x);
//x:10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem is, that "click" happens sometime in the future, after user interaction.

`for` loop in your example creates `onPress` callback function - all good here. The problem here is at the time of press event, `i` equals to 10 in every case. It is not bound!

I will show two examples where I try to explain solution of this problem for you.

### `for` loop

First uses `for` loop and binds `i` to callback function.

```
const array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  function bindIndex(boundIndex) {
    return {
      onPress: () => console.log(boundIndex)
    }
  }

  array.push(bindIndex(i))
}

array[5].onPress()
```

### `Array.map`

In second example, array of length of 10 is created and mapped into new array with indexes bound already.

```
// Create array of length of N (10 in this case)
const arrOfN = Array.from(Array(10))

const array = arrOfN.map((value, index) => ({
  onPress: () => console.log(index)
}))

array[5].onPress()
```

Choose solution that fits you best and adjust your code accordingly.

Running [example here](http://jsbin.com/xegasiwezi/edit?js,console)

Comment: With a few changes to make it react-native friendly, this works great! thank you for the help.